# How to explode string by uppercase and generate more rows [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

here is my question

If I have dataframe like:

```
         Metropolitan area Population                     NHL
0            New York City   20153634  RangersIslandersDevils
1              Los Angeles   13310447              KingsDucks
2               Washington   23131112              New London
3                  Alabama   11111112                Lighting
```

I want to get a new dataframe like:

```
         Metropolitan area Population                     NHL
0            New York City   20153634                 Rangers
1            New York City   20153634               Islanders
2            New York City   20153634                  Devils
3              Los Angeles   13310447                   Kings
4              Los Angeles   13310447                   Ducks
5               Washington   23131112              New London
6                  Alabama   11111112                Lighting
```

So, as you can see, I need to split NHL team names by upper case, but if there is a space in the name, should not do anything.

Comment: Do you have a list of **NHL team names**?

Comment: Yes, in the NHL column (in this example df has 3 columns including this NHL column)

Comment: You misunderstand my question. Not everybody is familiar with NHL, how do we know that `Rangers` is a team name, not `RangersIslander`?

Comment: Aha, I know that from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_and_Canadian_cities_by_number_of_major_professional_sports_franchises

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `findall` and `explode`:

```
out = (
    df.assign(NHL=df["NHL"].str.findall(r"[A-Z](?:\s[A-Z]|[^A-Z])+"))
    .explode("NHL")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(out)
  Metropolitan area  Population         NHL
0     New York City    20153634     Rangers
1     New York City    20153634   Islanders
2     New York City    20153634      Devils
3       Los Angeles    13310447       Kings
4       Los Angeles    13310447       Ducks
5        Washington    23131112  New London
6           Alabama    11111112    Lighting
```

Comment: I borrowed your regex solution.  :) +1 good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
df.drop('NHL', axis=1).merge(df['NHL'].str.extractall('([A-Z](?:\s[A-Z]|[^A-Z])+)')
                                      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                                      .rename(columns={0:'NHL'}), 
                             left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
 Metropolitan area  Population         NHL
0     New York City    20153634     Rangers
0     New York City    20153634   Islanders
0     New York City    20153634      Devils
1       Los Angeles    13310447       Kings
1       Los Angeles    13310447       Ducks
2        Washington    23131112  New London
3           Alabama    11111112    Lighting
```

Borrowed @CameronRiddell regex to correct parse teams.

Comment: This separate `New London` :-)

Comment: ARG!!!  @QuangHoang You're right.  We need a list that holds all the team names.

Comment: Okay, I borrowed @CameronRiddell regex solution.

Comment: Thanks for credit for the regex! As an extra note for your answer, you can simplify any call to `merge(..., left_index=True, right_index=True)` by using `.join(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be updated:

```
import re
df1 = df[df["NHL"].str.contains(" ")]
df2 = df[~df["NHL"].str.contains(" ")]
df2["NHL"] = df2.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*", x["NHL"]), axis=1)
df2 = df2.explode("NHL")
pd.concat([df2,df1])
```